# Java Timezone: why Offset is needed

Tags: java

My requirment is like this:

I am saving time in millisecond in database and the timezone.For example the time in milisecond is  `1223123123232` in long and timezone is `Asia/Calcutta`. I have to convert it to `Africa/Asmara` timezone.

```
long l = 1223123123232l;
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta");
long tzOff = tz.getOffset(l);
java.util.Date d = new Date(l-tzOff);   // WHY THIS??
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Africa/Asmara"));// required timezone
String s = df.format(d);
System.out.println(s);
```

To check i am refering this: [link](http://www.timezoneconverter.com/cgi-bin/tzc.tzc)

My question is:

1. If the timezone is just the representation of time in different formats(geographical areas offset from GMT),why do i need to subtract the offset time form the actual time `(l-tzOff)`?
2. Why can't i ignore the timezone which is saved in Database, and only consider the timezome in which i want to convert the date?

Something like:

```
long l = 1223123123232l;
java.util.Date d = new Date(l);
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Africa/Asmara"));// required timezone
String s = df.format(d);
System.out.println(s);
```

**My system timezone is `Asia/Calcutta`, i want to convert a Date in `Africa/Bujumbura` timezone to `Europe/Vatican` timezone.The above code is not working in this case? Why this is so?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Java dates do not know about time zones](http://tshikatshikaaa.blogspot.nl/2012/09/about-java-timezone-and-calendar-caveats.html). Therefore, if I save 14H00 in New-York, it will not be the same 14H00 as in Paris, although the millisecond value is the same. You need to use a unique reference to save dates. People often chose GMT+0.

If you need to check local time across timezones, you can use a tool I developed [here](http://yourworldclocks.juplo.com/).

To answer your questions:

1. Timezone is not a representation of time, it is a localisation of time. The reason you would substract an offset is to make sure all time is defined according to the same reference.
2. Because you would get false results and false dates.

Comment: Sir, my default timezone is `Asia/Calcutta`. I want to convert a date from `Libya` timezone to `Africa/Bujumbura`. The above code what i pasted is not giving correct Result?

Comment: No. You should use the code example available at the link I posted at the beginning of my answer. See the 'Converting A Date Between Time Zones' section.

Answer (score 1):

[`new Date(long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28long%29) takes the number of milliseconds since the **GMT** epoch. Since in your case `l` is the number of milliseconds since some other point in time (namely 1 Jan 1970, 00:00:00 in Asia/Calcutta), you have to convert it to GMT first. This is done by subtracting the relevant timezone offset.

Comment: Thnx for the reply sir, But, if i am not wrong, there is only one Epoch.

Comment: @RiteshKaushik: Exactly. However, your `l` isn't the offset from the epoch, it's the offset from some other point in time, and you need to correct for that.

Comment: Sir, my default timezone is `Asia/Calcutta`. I want to convert a date from `Libya` timezone to `Africa/Bujumbura`. The above code what i pasted is not giving correct Result?