# Java TimeZone conversion issue

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Timezone: why Offset is needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705561/java-timezone-why-offset-is-needed)

My system timezone is `Asia/Calcutta`.My requirment is to convert time in one timezone to other.

```
long l = 1223123123232l;// long value representing the date.
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Sydney");// First Time zone
long tzOff = tz.getOffset(l);
java.util.Date d = new Date(l-tzOff);   // WHY THIS??
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Africa/Asmara"));// Required Time zone
String s = df.format(d);
System.out.println(s);
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Didn't you very recently post an identical question?

Comment: yes sir, but i am facing this problem now, need to urgently fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate question and already resolved.

Use [Java Timezone: why Offset is needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705561/java-timezone-why-offset-is-needed)

OR

Try below

```
Date date = new Date();
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");     
System.out.println("Default time, timezone EST : "+dateFormat.format(date));        
TimeZone t1 = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta");

dateFormat.setTimeZone(t1);
System.out.println("Converted time, timezone IST : "+dateFormat.format(date));
```